# How to avoid Graphviz dot layouts wasting space, with nodes of disparate sizes at the same rank?

Tags: graphviz, dot

When one has a graphviz directed graph that is best suited to arrange using dot, is there a way to get around the issue of a large node creating excess padding around other nodes of the same rank?

For example, with the following graph:

```
digraph {
    b[label="line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\n"];

    a -> b;
    a -> c;
    b -> f;
    c -> d;
    d -> e;
    e -> f;
}
```

[image: (result of the above)]

The graph is obviously taller than necessary due to the left-hand path increasing the height of a rank that doesn't need to be so tall in the right-hand path.

Is there perhaps a way to do layout the two paths separately? I thought using cluster subgraphs might help, but it seems that rank heights are completely global even in that case.

I'm hoping for a result akin to this image edit (please excuse it's crudeness):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you may try to add `edge[constraint = false];`. 
This will set [`constraint`](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint) attribute value for all edges:
[image: Rendered graph]

Or specify `constraint` attribute only for some of *edges*.

---

**EDIT:** Quite close result we can achieve with the help of subgraphs:

```
digraph {

    rankdir = LR;

    b[label="line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\n"];

    subgraph cluster_0 {

        rank = same;

        style = invis;

        a -> c -> d -> e -> f [constraint = false];

    }

    a -> b;
    b -> f;

}
```

Will be rendered as follows: 
[image: Rendered graph]

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't at all address what I'm asking for. That just results in moving all of the nodes to the same rank, whereas what I need is for the two paths from node 'a' to node 'f' to still be side by side vertically, but without the height of node 'b' increasing the padding of things on the other path.
I've edited the question to include a clarifying picture.

Comment: @Rednaxela I've updated answer, new result looks quite similar to your second illustration.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. That's clever, using a "rankdir = LR" style graph with and producing vertical subsections with nodes at the same rank in that fashion. Now, that works well enough in this simple example, however it does restrict nodes to being vertically aligned in column. I don't think this approach generalizes well to the larger graphs with more branching I'll be dealing with for that reason.Thanks though